# Symmetrize a histogram plot or array?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, scipy, histogram

I have a histogram that runs from -5 to 5 that I can manipulate and plot as I please, and I use the following PDF's to run one-sample KS tests on it: norm, cauchy, students t, laplace.

However, I have to symmetrize the data (make it go from only 0 to 5) and run KS tests on that. Which is fine for norm and cauchy.. but I cannot find a "half students t" PDF in scipy.stats

So I would really appreciate your help either:

1) in how to plot a histogram going from 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, ... back on up, where there are no negatives, that doesn't just show 0 to 5 and I can just set loc=0 as per usual for my KS test. (I wish I could just do a plt.MirroredAboutX() or something?) Or,

2) does anyone know if a half students t PDF is hiding somewhere I glossed over?

Thanks!

**Edit**: Giving clarification to #1 above, using this list

```
l = [-1.93067027 -1.00267766 -0.6349767  -0.82698775 -0.59277326 -0.67801007 -0.60888202 -0.27387228 -0.03645225 -0.02120668  0.02004329  0.40640109 0.661673 0.77414735  0.86466529  0.53162743  0.64943555  0.7827397 1.8450599   1.44000795]
```

`plt.hist(l)` shows me a histogram from -2 to 2, 
[image]

and `plt.hist(np.abs(l))` shows me a histogram from 0 to 2. 
[image]

I want the histogram that goes from 0 to 2, to now be mirrored/flipped over the y-axis so that the range of the x-axis is from 2 to 2 (since it's centered at 0) and it is this nice symmetric, plotted histogram.

Comment: I wonder if this is the same as doing a histogram for the absolute values. histogram(abs(x)). Apart, it would really make sense to provide a sample code of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, I have updated my question.

Comment: That's better. But if you flip the histogram, wouldn't you get wrong values out? The values on the y-axis would not actually correspond to any reasonable number any more, right?

Comment: They would and would simply be mirrored values, I just need it to be flipped so that i can utilize the KS test for more than a Gaussian or Cauchy. Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may plot a bar chart of the results of a numpy histogramming. You can then invert the arrays to plot a mirrored version of them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

l = "-1.93067027 -1.00267766 -0.6349767 -0.82698775 -0.59277326 -0.67801007 -0.60888202 -0.27387228 -0.03645225 -0.02120668  0.02004329  0.40640109 0.661673 0.77414735  0.86466529  0.53162743  0.64943555  0.7827397 1.8450599   1.44000795"
l = np.array(list(map(lambda x: float(x),l.split() )))

step = 0.25
bins = np.arange(0,2.01, step)
hist, edges = np.histogram(np.abs(l),bins=bins)

plt.bar(bins[:-1], hist, width=step, align="edge", ec="k")

plt.bar(-bins[::-1][:-1], hist[::-1], width=step, align="edge", ec="k")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that doing this, the y axis has lost its quantitative meaning, as each values is accounted for twice in the mirrored plot.